# How to check for incorrect property names at compile time in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm getting started with angular and building a few practice apps. My background is mostly knockout.js, and so far I quite like much of what I'm seeing in Angular 2/4.

However, one thing strikes me as somewhat odd. In the process of learning, I've made several spelling mistakes or property errors (such as forgetting to use the loop variable in an ngFor), yet neither VS code, the CLI linter, nor angular itself throws any error. For example, if I have a property called `myProperty` in my component's .ts file, and I accidentally type `{{myProporty}}` into my html template, I get no error whatsoever. There is only a blank space and no output, and it's left to me to try and figure out what I did wrong. In a simple template this is easy enough, but at least once it held me up for a good while as I tried to figure out what I'd missed.

I noticed the linter actually *does* throw an error if the template is declared inline in the `@Component` decorator tag. In this case running ng lint gives me the error, `The property "myProporty" that you're trying to access does not exist in the class declaration.` However, no such error is thrown if my template is in its own html file.

I'm not sure if there's a "strict" setting I've missed, or if maybe this is just a tooling issue, but it seems odd for there not to be any sort of checking on this sort of thing. VS code also doesn't seem to have any sort of intellisense for these things, though that could be a VS code issue, I don't know.

Just wondering if anyone knows a plugin that can check for these things, or if there's a CLI command I missed or something.

Comment: Do you do ng lint ?

Comment: @Vega yes, as I said, ng lint does not (apparently) check html files. If there is an error in an inline template, it throws an error, but if it is in a separate file, nothing. There's also no dev tools error even when the app runs, which seems really strange since Angular must be evaluating these.

Comment: try to build with --prod option it will give all the errors `ng build --prod`

Comment: @Vega tried it, but unfortunately, the same issue as ng lint. It throws an error for the inline template, but no error for templates included using `templateUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone else knows a better solution, but I googled around and it seems like this html validation is a bit of an ongoing development area of Angular.

In the meantime, I did find a useful VS code extension that fixed my intellisense issue: https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service

The latest version (0.1.5) seems to be broken, but 0.1.4 gave me intellisense for all my html templates, which will help quite a lot, I think.

Comment: Yeah definitely an ongoing issue w/ angular.... I've tried using that plugin but it crashed so frequently for me that I eventually gave up on it.  I've just gotten used to no error checking in my templates :-(